# Changing the place of contents in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to change “contents” word to the right. How can I do it?

[image: tableo]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\usepackage{theorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        filecolor=blue,      
        urlcolor=blue,
        citecolor=red,
        linktoc=page
        %pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

\begin{document}
\dominitoc

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{This is the first chapter}

{\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\minitoc
}

\section{section}
This is a citation~\cite{ref1}. Theorem~\ref{thm1} provides some interesting information.
\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
    Rain gets you wet.
\end{theorem}
\section{section}
\section{section}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\begin{thebibliography}{Smi19}

    \bibitem[Smi19]{ref1}
    John Smith.
    \newblock Citing in red.
    \newblock {\em Journal of Hyperlink Colors}, 2019.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remember to load [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package without the `[titles]` option:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries} % for ToC title
\renewcommand*{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries} % for LoF title
\renewcommand*{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries} % for LoT title
```

Comment: It did work! One more question, how can I add the list of symbols, and list of abbreviations?

Comment: @Delan And how do you get your lists of symbols and abbreviations?  How can anybody answer if we don't know what you have done?

Comment: `\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols, title = List of Symbols]`

Comment: @Delan your `\printunsrtglossary ...` by itself doesn't help. Extend your MWE.

Answer (score 1):

After loading [`minitoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/minitoc), add the following code to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{
  \patchcmd{\mtc@sv@tableofcontents}% <cmd>
    {\contentsname}% <search>
    {\mbox{}\hfill\contentsname}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

The above patch updates the `\tableofcontents` saved by [`minitoc`](//ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) to insert `\hfill` before the printed title. `minitoc` completely removed the functionality of [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) here.

Comment: Great! Does it work also with the list of figures and list of abbreviations